# ReactJs / Typescript How to pass an array of objects into interface props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have two interfaces which looks like this.

```
export interface TableBoxPropsHeader{
    name: string,
    isIconOnly: boolean
}

export interface TableBoxProps<T> {
 headerNames: TableBoxPropsHeader[],
 // some stuff
}
```

I am trying to create a variable with this definition, but for some reason it says I am trying to pass a `string[]` array instead of a `TableBoxPropsHeader[]` array.

```
private tableBoxProps: TableBoxProps<SomeType> = {
  headerNames: [{name: "Name", isIconOnly:false}, {name: "Category", isIconOnly:true}],
```

I am using VSCode and it does not complain about the above. But the npm prints the following

```
Types of property 'headerNames' are incompatible.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'TableBoxPropsHeader[]'
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TableBoxPropsHeader'.
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I create an array of an interface?

Answer (score 0):

Allright, this is somewhat stupid of me. There was another variable in a different file with the error. It works perfectly fine now...